# Wall Cupboard on my single brick wall

Tags: walls

Can i hang a wall-cupboard on my single brick wall which is about 3*6 ft? Actually i want to make some cupboard on upper side of the wall, so can i? These would be efficient or not?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There isn't enough information to answer here; perhaps some pictures and/or a digram would help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: In what way would you expect a cupboard to be efficient? How _thick_ is the brick? What kind of condition is it in? Is it new, with good quality mortar, or is it older with crumbling mortar? We're going to need more detail to help answer this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "single brick wall"  A wall with one brick or one wall made of brick? What kind of brick?  **What is your goal and what is your question? How to mount it securely?**    @FreeMan "*How thick is the brick?*"   "And your wise men don't know how it feels, To be thick as a brick"